# No sound with a Creative Sound Blaster ZxR soundcard on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, soundcard, sound-blaster

First of all.
I know that there is no offcial driver support on their website.

But the sound card is at least recognized in the sound-settings.
So... is there a way to get the ZxR working?
I tried to install the windows-drivers via wine but of course with no success.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you made sure that it's not muted? Try running `alsamixer` in the terminal and double check volume settings.

Comment: It is still an unsolved problem https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=55541

Answer (score -1):

if i open in a terminal following command i have sound on my headphones wich stuck at my frontpanel. but microphone doesn't work.

```
sudo kill `ps uax |grep pulseaudio | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
sudo rmmod snd-hda-intel
sleep 3
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```

Comment: -1 I'm pretty sure that `snd-hda-intel` is not the right driver for Creative sound cards.

Comment: This reads more like a comment instead of an answer to the question